# vNext build process : How to push the file after updating, back to tfs git?

Tags: git, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We have vNext build setup for official releases. We are using Tfs 2015 vNext build with git version control. During the automated build process, we update one version file with powershell script. And we want to push it back to repository after the file being updated with new version.

Any help in this regards really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is too vague. Could you ask a clearer question on your real problem, not just asking for help? And explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve.... You want to require to push a file once updated? That's not possible with git. Except if you write your own TFS policy if you have some data to verify that the dev forgot to commit the file...

Comment: @philippe sorry for being vague,  i edited my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build server should have git in the path and you just have, in your build process to :

1. git add your_file
2. git commit -m "update version by the build"
3. git rebase (in case your build is long and someone already pushed something else)
4. git push

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Video 2 in this short series (20 min) will show you how to exactly configure what you need and provides hand on examples of changing a file and pushing back to Git. Hope this helps https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/enabling-devops-practices-with-visual-studio-online-build-12478?l=Gwpyl6BOB_4305094681